# Java get remainder versus bit shift

Tags: java, benchmarking, java-12

As we all know that there is a treat to get remainder for:

m = Remainder

n = The number

d = The divisor, a positive integer

m = n & ( d - 1 )

It works for d = 2^k (k is a positive integer)

For JDK 12, I use jmh to test the efficiency:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class Generator {
    SequentialGenerator sequentialGenerator = new SequentialGenerator(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    SequentialGenerator powerGenerator = new SequentialGenerator(1, 17);
}

@Benchmark
@Warmup(iterations = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 120)
public void mod2_1(Generator generator) {

    int pow = generator.powerGenerator.nextValue().intValue();
    int factor = 1 << pow;
    int i = generator.sequentialGenerator.nextValue().intValue();

    for (long j = 0; j < 1000L; j++) {
        int k = i & (factor -1);
    }
}

@Benchmark
@Warmup(iterations = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 120)
public void mod2_2(Generator generator) {

    int pow = generator.powerGenerator.nextValue().intValue();
    int factor = 1 << pow;
    int i = generator.sequentialGenerator.nextValue().intValue();

    for (long j = 0; j < 1000L; j++) {
        int k = i % factor;
    }
}
```

The result shows that % is more efficient than &, why is that:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt        Score       Error  Units
BitUtilTest.mod2_1       thrpt  120  1218565.022 ± 32816.798  ops/s
BitUtilTest.mod2_2       thrpt  120  2045390.684 ± 56090.355  ops/s
```

Comment: Looks like a very small loop, which could be removed.

Comment: for the consideration of the overheads brought by the previous fetch parameter codes

Comment: You don't use `k`, and the calculation can be hoisted out of the loop. But if it isn't optimized away then note that *signed* remainder is not the same thing as `i & mask`.  (Unless the JVM manages to optimize based on the fact that `i` is known positive, if it manages to propagate that through the PRNG.)

Comment: You are using JMH, but not in the intended way, but rather making all the mistakes that a proper use of JMH ought to avoid. First, don’t write a loop, JMH does already do (that’s what “iterations” parameter is all about), second don’t mix the code for generating input value and the actual operation under test, third, ensure that the result value can not be considered “unused” by the optimizer. If you fixed the first two points, that’s as easy as implementing the whole method as `return value % divisor;` resp. `return value >> shift;`